# grid binding to a listbox selecteditem runtime

Tags: listbox, grid, selecteditem, data-binding

I am a beginner, so please bear with me.

Let's say we have a listbox and a grid that contains textblocks on a window. But these are instanced from separate xaml files, and added to two different stackpanels in the window.

How can I bind the grid datasource to the listbox's selected item in runtime?

I guess what I need to do is to do this following xaml in runtime:

```
Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstContacts, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the Window's Loaded event, and in your handler: traverse your Window's children using VisualTreeHelper to find your ListBox based on its name, then set your Grid's DataContext.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls) is a question that discusses, and provides a method for, finding children in such a manner.